# navigationController?.pushViewController fails to launch the view

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, navigationcontroller

Language is Swift 4

I have a tableView which is showing some categories and below each category it has one or more detail rows. When I click on the detail row, I want it to launch another tableView to show the selected detail row, along with some additional information pertaining to the selected detail row.

To this end, I have implemented the following function:

```
// launch the detail view controller
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let detailView = DetailVC()
    detailView.customInit(detailID: tempViewData[indexPath.section].detailIDs[indexPath.row])
    setupTableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailView, animated: true)
}
```

However, when I run the app, while no errors are listed, the detail view does not launch.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you put this viewController in a UINavigationController and set the setupTableView's delegate to this viewController

Comment: I'm not totally certain what you're asking.  In this view controller's viewDidLoad function, I have added:  setupTableView.delegate = self

Comment: but it doesn't display the detail view controller.

Comment: Then the most likely cause is that `self.navigationController` is `nil` - Have you embedded your view controller in a navigation controller?

Comment: Is this `didSelectRowAt` method being called? If so, if `self.navigationController` a non-nil value?

Comment: I have not embedded the setupTableView controller in a navigation controller.  I setup the UI using the storyboard and have created 3 view controllers, but no navigation controller.  I'm using a segue to move from the first view controller (which is just a screen with some buttons on it) to the setupVC, and this works properly.  I have a navigation bar at the top to provide a Back button.  I tried using a segue in place of the self.navigationController?.pushViewController line, but that resulted in an error.  Do I need to embed everything in a navigation controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select your first viewController in `Storyboard`, then embed it into a UINavigationController from the menu like this.
[image]

Comment: This worked, however now from my initial view controller, when I click on the button to display the SetupVC, it displays it for a second, then it displays it again.  Why would it do this?

Comment: Ok, I resolved the problem.  On my initial view controller I had setup a segue to the SetupVC.  I then had created an action outlet from the same button and called the segue function.  I commented out this segue call and things are working properly now.

Answer (score 0):

Use self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:kCreateFBAccountVCID ) as! DetailVC Instead of  DetailVC()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) 
{

```
let detailView = **self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:kCreateFBAccountVCID ) as! DetailVC**
detailView.customInit(detailID: tempViewData[indexPath.section].detailIDs[indexPath.row])
setupTableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailView, animated: true)}
```